# Hom ring of any ideal of any integral domain is commutative?

Tags: ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals, integral-domain

Let $R$ be an integral domain (a commutative ring with unity without non-zero zero divisor) ; $I$ be an ideal of $R$ , so that $I$ is an $R$-module .  Let $f,g : I \to I$ be any two $R$-module homomorphisms . Then is it true that $f \circ g = g\circ f $ ? I have no idea where to start ; and I have no intuition as  to the validity of the statement . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: In what context did you find it? A text? After some certain theorems? What do you know?

Comment: @rschwieb : A friend of mine mentioned that perhaps he saw a remark like this in a paper ; but he couldn't actually remember . We saw that it is easy to workout if $R$ is a PID but couldn't settle it in the general . Now I have found a paper (which is most definitely "the" paper my friend saw) claiming the statement is true and well known . Here is the link . http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1973-037-01/S0002-9939-1973-0311651-0/S0002-9939-1973-0311651-0.pdf . See the very first paragraph in the beginning .

Comment: I am familiar with the problem through a more general problem that I once saw as an exercise in a text. See the end of my post...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Lemma:** in the context above, $fg(y)=gf(y)$ for all $y\in I^2$.
>
> *Proof:* Let $i,j\in I$. Then $(fg-gf)(ij)=fg(ij)-gf(ij)=f(g(i)j)-g(if(j))=f(j)g(i)-f(j)g(i)=0$. Since this holds for all $i,j$, it holds for all elements of $I^2$.

Notice that the above holds for any commutative ring $R$.

*Proof of your problem*:

> Suppose $(fg-gf)(x)=z\neq 0$ for some $x\in I$. Then $(fg-gf)(x^2)=(fg-gf)(x)x=zx\neq 0$ also. But by the lemma we know this cannot be the case since $x^2\in I^2$.

Now actually I remember the version of this question I solved long ago:

> **Proposition:** Let $I$ be an ideal of a commutative ring $R$ such that $I$ contains a regular element $r$ (that is, $r$ isn't a zero divisor.)  Then $End(I_R)$ is commutative.

The proof is the same, except that when you arrive at "Suppose $(fg-gf)(x)=z\neq 0$ for some $x\in I$", you take your special regular element $r\in I$ and say that "$(fg-gf)(xr)=(fg-gf)(x)r=zr\neq 0$, a contradiction."

Comment: This generalization can also be proved : Let $I$ be an ideal of a commutative ring $R$ such that $I$ has no nonzero nilpotent , then $Hom_R(I,I)$ is commutative .

Indeed if $x\in I$ and $z=(fg-gf)(x)$ , then $z \in I$ , and so by the Lemma , $0=(fg-gf)(zx)=z.(fg-gf)(x)=z^2$ , hence $z=0$ i.e. $fg(x)=gf(x)$

Comment: @users yes, also true